# Summand, integrand ... limmand for term inside the limit?

Tags: limits, terminology

Is [limmand](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22limmand%22) legit?

There's integrand $f(x) dx$ for integrals $\int f(x) dx$, [summand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161072/what-is-the-thing-inside-a-sum-called) $a_n$ for sums $\sum_n a_n$, [multiplicand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4443063/summand-is-to-sum-left-sum-right-as-is-to-product-left-prod-ri) (?) $a_n$ for products $\prod_n a_n$ and [uniands $A_n$ (?) / intersectands $A_n$ (?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484667/analogue-of-the-term-summand-for-unions-and-intersections) for unions / intersections $\cup_n A_n$ / $\cap_n A_n$ ...

So there's... limmand $a_n$ or $f(x)$ for limits, resp, $\lim_n a_n$ or $\lim_{x \to \text{whatever}} f(x)$ ?

Comment: I'd personally prefer 'limitand' since I think it rolls off the tongue better, but I don't believe there's any particular method to how words are inflected like that, beyond popular usage or sounding natural. And at the end of the day, you can call it whatever you want, as long as you're clear with your definitions and consistent. You could call it a 'blarg', for that matter. Why should one dictionary trump another?

Comment: I agree with @Jam, call it whatever is understandable. Pretty much all uses of the word limmand come from me on this site, but what I appreciate about the word is its technical simplicity - even though it is not widespread, clarity is not lost and everyone reading the answer knows immediately to what I am referring. Before constants had agreed upon values, mathematicians would constantly redefine their values for whatever context they had on hand (for example, defining $\pi$ as being a full rotation, half rotation, or quarter rotation of the circle for whatever was natural for the proof)